# How can I have my query return the column names along with the corresponding data in MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Suppose I have a MariaDB table like this:

| ID | foo | bar | fizz | buzz | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 0 | 2 | 0 | 3 | ... |
| def | 14 | 0 | 0 | 1 | ... |
| ghi | 3 | 9 | 0 | 0 | ... |
| ... | ... |  |  |  |  |

With a single query, I want to retrieve the data for one row, but **also** get the column names at the same time.  For instance, if I'm querying for the item with ID `abc`, this is what I want to receive:

| ID | foo | bar | fizz | buzz |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 0 | 2 | 0 | 3 |

I don't just want to get the row values `(abc, 0 , 2, 0, 3)`, I also want the column names to be joined to the result.  Something like `((ID, abc), (foo,0), (bar,2), (fizz,0), (buzz,3))`

I don't want to use a separate query like `DESCRIBE foobar;`, or  `SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name='foobar'`, because the table has 200 columns and some 100,000 rows, so manually joining the two pieces of information would be very time-comsuming.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  You already know the column names, why do you need them returned in the query?

Comment: You can just add the literal string to the `SELECT` query, something like: `SELECT "foo", foo FROM foobar where ID = "abc"`.

Comment: Is there a programming language (like PHP, Python, etc.) here or is this just a SQL question.  Most languages have SQL libraries that can get you this info with your `SELECT *` or whatever query.

Comment: Because I'm using `SELECT * FROM foobar` to get the entire row.  There are over 200 columns.

Comment: Where is the result being used?  How/where are you running the query?

Comment: *"I don't want to use a separate query"* - Except that's where that information is stored, so a separate query is exactly what you want.  *"manually joining the two pieces of information would be very time-comsuming"* - Why do you want to manually join them?  Why wouldn't something like a `UNION` work?  Why do you even need or *want* these to be in the same query, since they're entirely different data?  Can't the application show the column names from one query and the results from another?  This sounds like an XY Problem.  What's the reason for wanting this?